# XAxis labels for an irregular set of data on highcharts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am using highcharts with ASP.NET MVC to draw graphs of data gathered lively from some temperature sensors. The sensors send data in an average duration of five minutes. However they are not always working. I used points of (x,y) with x being the minutes from some starting date and y being the temperature. With x values in this method I get the proper irregular shape of graph as desired. However it seems that Categories are not working here since those x values are not integers corresponding to indices of categories array. I need my XAxis labels to be regular date ticks however I can't use the Datetime XAxis type here since the datetime values are not essentially Gregorian and differ from user's choice of culture. Any idea?

Comment: Generally when you use time data, you should use timestamps and datetime xAxis

Comment: The problem is that the default datetimes are shown in Persian calendar and I don't know if the datetime xAxis is applicable here.